# only particular no of bytes are written each time in php

Tags: android

code below upload a video file from android to webserver using php but fwrite appends only 24 bytes each time. even buffer size is greater than 24 bytes.why it is happening.what is wrong.is there is any other efficent way to upload large file to server so that there not much memory consumption on both android and server side.

```
imports ...

public class Upload extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

private static final int SELECT_AUDIO = 2;
private HttpURLConnection conn = null;
private String boundary =  "*****";
String responseFromServer = "";
private FileInputStream fileInputStream;
private URL url;

public void doFileUpload(String selectedPath){

    try
    {
        //------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
         fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        String urlString = "http://localhost/video.php";
         url = new URL(urlString);
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                   write();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    doFileUpload(params[0]);
    return null;
}

public void write(){
     try {
         conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         // Allow Inputs
         conn.setDoInput(true);
         // Allow Outputs
         conn.setDoOutput(true);
         // Don't use a cached copy.
         conn.setUseCaches(false);
         // Use a post method.
         conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
         conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

         DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
         String lineEnd = "\r\n";
         String twoHyphens = "--";
         dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + "video" + "\"" + lineEnd);

        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        // create a buffer of maximum size

         int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;


        // read file and write it into form...

         int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
         int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
         fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);    
          dos.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // close streams
        Log.e("Debug","File is written");
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
        //------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            DataInputStream inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            String str;

            while (( str = inStream.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.e("Debug","Server Response "+str);
            }
            inStream.close();

        }
        catch (IOException ioex){
            Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ioex.getMessage(), ioex);
        }

        try {
            if (fileInputStream.available()>0){
                write();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


<?php

  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
  $file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
  $file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
  $temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];

  $location = "uploads/";

  $pointer=fopen($location.$file_name,'ab');

  $twmp=fwrite($pointer,$temp_name);
  echo $twmp;
 }else{
    echo "Error";
 }
```

log is

```
    04-19 09:28:08.895 14999-15564/android.example.com.videouploader E/Debug: File is written
    04-19 09:28:08.999 14999-15564/android.example.com.videouploader E/Debug: Server Response 24
    04-19 09:28:09.081 14999-15564/android.example.com.videouploader E/Debug: File is written
    04-19 09:28:09.335 14999-15564/android.example.com.videouploader E/Debug: Server Response 24
    04-19 09:28:09.402 14999-15564/android.example.com.videouploader E/Debug: File is written
    04-19 09:28:09.511 14999-15564/android.example.com.videouploader E/Debug: Server Response 24

    more like this
```

Comment: `InputStream.available()` is not doing what you think. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--

Comment: it works well if  move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location.$temp_name); is used in file php instead of appending to file.